# How to compile a c++ program with std::bind?

Tags: c++, g++, debian

I want to compile this simple test.cpp program from [Wrox's Professional C++](http://books.google.pl/books?id=sN_0ovp_yv4C&pg=PT506&dq=c%2B%2B+bind&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nKINUqaNG42Wswakq4H4BQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=c%2B%2B%20bind&f=false):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>
using namespace std;

void func(int num, const string& str)
{
            cout << num << ' ' << str << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string str = "abc";
    auto f = bind(func, placeholders::_1, str);
    f(16);
}
```

I have g++ (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5 compilator and I use it like that:

```
g++ -std = c++0x test.cpp -o test
```

I get error:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind<void (*(std::_Placeholder<1>, int))
(int, int)>) (int)’
```

Why the program does not compile?

I cannot compile the example program from [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/) as well.

Comment: Works for me (GCC 4.8.1). You probably need to update your compiler.

Comment: After `apt-get install g++`, I get message "the program is already in the latest version". Is it possible to upgrade g++ 4.4 in Debian Squeeze?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::bind` is C++11, which is not supported by g++ 4.4 You need to upgrade at least to Debian Wheezy's g++ 4.7 by system upgrade or using /etc/apt/preferences package bindings

Comment: GCC publishes a list of supported C++11 features at http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html. Unfortunately I couldn't find the feature that includes the `std::bind` function template.

Comment: D'oh, of course I could not find it there as it is not a language feature but a library feature. It is a part of libstdc++ which lists its C++11 implementation status here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011 Unfortunately they don't specify the version at which the features were implemented.